# BitmapImage created on separate thread and frozen does not show

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I have an `Image` with `Source` bound to a view model `BitmapImage` property.  Its an icon to show for each tree view item in a tree view.  I want to load the images in a separate thread to reduce blocking of the UI thread during initialisation of the tree.

I have read various answers to similar questions but I have not yet found the solution to this particular problem.  I am aware that to make a `BitmapImage` available across threads you have to `Freeze` the image but it is this freezing that stops it rendering.

I load the image as follows:

```
private void LoadImage()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_imagePath))
            return ;
        string[] resources = GetResourceNames();
        var result = resources?.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x, _image, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ??
                     resources?.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(Path.GetFileName(x), _imagePath, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        var image = result == null ? null : new BitmapImage(GetUri(ImageResourceCache.ImagesAssembly.FullName, result));
        if (image == null) return;

        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; //<== a suggested solution that does not make a difference
        image.Freeze();//<== freezing stops the cross thread exception but stops rendering

        DispatcherHelp.CheckInvokeOnUI(() => Image = image);
    });
}

private static string[] GetResourceNames()
{
    var asm = ImageResourceCache.ImagesAssembly;
    var resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
    {
        if (stream == null) return null;
        using (var reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
            return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
    }
}

private static Uri GetUri(string dllName, string relativeFilePath)
{
    return new Uri($"/{dllName};component/{relativeFilePath}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

`LoadImage` is called in the view model Constructor.  The _imagePath is passed to the constructor.

If I remove the Task.Run and the freeze it renders.  Put the freeze back and it no longer renders.

Binding is as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0 0 3 0" />
```

viewmodel:

```
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get => _image;
    set
    {
        _image = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0 0 3 0" />  LoadImage is called in the constructor

Comment: Do you try to create it in main thread? Maybe image can not show this stream

Comment: no i'm creating it in a separate thread (Task.Run) hence the need to Freeze the image

Comment: @TimRutter Could you try to set the Image control's source? Do not using bind.

Comment: Image property yes see above - raise property changed.  DispatcherHelp.CheckInvokeOnUI - checks whether the current thread context is ui thread and if not invokes it on the main thread.  This is needed otherwise an exception is raised along the lines of cannot access object because another thread owns it

Comment: @TimRutter I not sure whether it is break in bind or you can not create the image by ` new BitmapImage(GetUri(ImageResourceCache.ImagesAssembly.FullName, result))`. Because the GetUri will return a uri and do you sure the code can read it in task?

Comment: If i remove Task.Run and .Freeze above it loads fine.  So all the other code works - at least it does when run in the UI thread

Comment: @TimRutter I do not sure the code `new BitmapImage(GetUri(ImageResourceCache.ImagesAssembly.FullName, result))` can read the uri resource in task

Comment: ok in that case how do I resolve that problem?

Comment: You can read the stream to memory stream in main thread and then load the image in task

Comment: BUt doesn't that just mean I'm still doing all the work in the main thread?

Comment: @TimRutter Read the resource to memory stream is fast. But loading the image is slow and it work in task.

Comment: thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me whether it can fix

Comment: @lindexi I think you've seen but the answer below solved the problem.  Thanks for your idea though, I didn't quite get to the point where I tried it unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) to identify the image resouce. This should work provided that there is an image/pic.jpeg resource:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.jpeg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    image.Freeze();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Image = image));
});
```

Your `GetUri` method seems to be missing the `pack://application:,,,/` part. There is no reason to look up the resources like you are currently doing when you can use a pack URI.

Comment: @lindexi: The above code works just fine for me. Pack URIs work on any thread.

Comment: So I say `maybe`

Comment: @lindexi: Because `pack://application:,,,/` is missing from the `Uri`.

Comment: thats it, thanks.  I've added pack://application:,,,/ to the GetUri and it works.  And you are correct I don't need to loop up resources.  This is actually used to load a DevExpress image and I think this is code they sent me.